# What kind of topological invariants can you get from just Hopf algebras?

Tags: co.combinatorics, hopf-algebras

In [A minus sign that used to annoy me but now I know why it is there](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/%7Eptingley/lecturenotes/minus-sign-Dec16-2015.pdf), Peter Tingley shows how to build knot invariants from the representations of the $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2) $ quantum group by comparing it to a certain algebra of ribbons.  This is to say the representation theory of  this quantum group is "tangled" in some way.

It is known that symmetric functions ([characters of the symmetric group $S_n$](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503040))  [form a Hopf algebra](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Eellis/ugrad_seminar_spring_2011/geissinger.pdf).    Is there a corresponding topological structure?

I'm just wondering if there's a diagrammatic way to look at representations of $S_n$. In general, does Hopf algebra structure of an algebra, imply there exists a diagrammatic way of looking at its representation theory?

---

More examples of [Hopf algebras](https://garsia.math.yorku.ca/%7Ezabrocki/talks/Hopfzoo.pdf) in combinatorics.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what king of topological structure you're hoping for? Like are you looking for a space whose cohomology is this Hopf algebra, or something like that?

Comment: If I only knew what I was looking for... from a quantum group you can get a knot invaraint b/c there is a functor from representations of quantum groups to a tangle category.

I am guessing that for $S_n$ you lose the crossings or something like that.  I'm just wondering if there's a diagrammatic way to look at representations of $S_n$.  

In general, does Hopf algebra structure of a ring, imply there exists a diagrammatic way of looking at its representation theory?

Comment: You should add the adjective "quasi-triangular" in front of "Hopf algebra." This condition exactly ensures that the category of representations is braided monoidal.

Comment: @John: the functor goes the other direction (from a tangle category to the category of representations). 

Comment: I mean it could be argued that what you are looking for is Dijkgraaf Witten theory http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/qg-winter2005/w05week06.pdf for a finite group. It is a 2d TQFT which tells a lot about the representation theory of G. For 3d you can get look at Chern-Simons theory for finite groups...



Comment: In principal in this way you can get a d-dimensional TQFT for any d from finite gauge theory....

Answer (score 6):

The category of finite-dimensional representations of a Hopf algebra has the structure of a monoidal category with duals. The comultiplication induces a monoidal structure, the tensor product of vector spaces. The counit induces a monoidal identity, the ground field. And the antipode induces a duality structure, the vector space dual. Thus, diagrammatically, you can think of intertwiners of representations of a Hopf algebra as being oriented curves with boundary embedded in a strip $\mathbb{R}\times\left[0,1\right]$. The boundary points would be colored by representations, with induced orientations $+$ or $-$ indicating whether we are considering the representation $V$ or its dual $V^\star$. Intertwiners would color the component curves with their orientation determining their source and target endpoints. A quasi-triangular Hopf algebra has an element $R\in H\otimes H$ which induces a braiding on its category of representations. A ribbon Hopf algebra is quasi-triangular and has an element $\theta\in H$ which induces a twist, thus making its category of representations a ribbon category, allowing one to notate intertwiners diagrammatically as colored, framed, oriented tangles.

Comment: This is really nice! Can you add some references?

Comment: One good reference is Yetter's Functorial Knot Theory. Another is Ohtsuki's Quantum Invariants. There's actually lots of books about this subject, these are just two that I really liked.